# Вывод цифры в ENTRY после нажатия

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Python window")
window.geometry("300x200")

btn1 = Button(text="1", height="3", width="3").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=80, pady=100)
entry = Entry(width=50)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)


window.mainloop()
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "1" в ENTRY выскакивала эта цифра?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Python window")
window.geometry("300x200")
entry = Entry(width=50)
entry.pack()
def ad2():
    entry.delete(0, END)
def ad():
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(END, '1')
btn1 = Button(text="1", height="3", width="3", command=ad).pack()
btn2 = Button(text="удалить", command=ad2).pack()
entry.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Даже с удалением)

Comment: Спасибо большое!